# In xUnit.net, is it possible to run tests in order?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, xunit.net, xunit

I know you generally should not depend on order for your unit tests, but in xunit is it possible to make your tests run in a certain order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the test case sequence in xUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210281/how-to-set-the-test-case-sequence-in-xunit)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a sample in our Samples project named PrioritizedFixtureSample which allows you to control the ordering of tests.

See the samples in our latest release: https://xunit.net/#releases

Comment: In short, the second parameter to the `[Fact]` method attribute is called `TestPriority` which in itself takes an integer (signed) representing the order of the tests. Exhibit A: `[Fact, TestPriority(5)]`. Just in case you didn't want to download and load up the example project...

Comment: `Fact` doesn't have seem to have `TestPriority` property anymore.

Comment: I don't think it was ever in xUnit itself, look up the sample Brad mentioned, the code for the attribute is in there.

Comment: I also created a version that executes modules alphabetically. And uses PriorityFixtures as well. So you can determine the exact ordering - if needed. (Class order through naming, like TestCase01, TestCase02, ...) http://www.andreas-reiff.de/2012/06/xunit-with-alphabetically-sorted-classes-and-proper-display-list-matching-execution-order/ , for a similar question and similar answers look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210281/how-to-set-the-test-case-sequence-in-xunit/11211507#comment20154201_11211507 .

Comment: `[TestPriority]` **IS NOT** part of `xUnit`. See the links provided by @AndreasReiff for implementation examples.

Answer (score 5):

No, I don't believe so, but then unit tests by definition should be independent so order *shouldn't* matter. Where you do have a natural dependency you can't separate I'd suggest you combine the tests into one unit with multiple asserts.

Answer (score 3):

xUnit.net does not provide a way to order tests.

Some other frameworks do, however.  For example, in mbUnit, you can attach an [Order](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/P_Gallio_Framework_Pattern_TestMethodPatternAttribute_Order.htm) property to your test attributes.  Many TDD purists feel that this is abusive, and any test that requires an order should be merged into a separate unit test, but many people find it useful to be able to order tests in certain circumstances.