# How to set the test case sequence in xUnit

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I have written the xUnit test cases in C#. That test class contains so many methods. I need  to run the whole test cases in a sequence. How can I set the test case sequence in xUnit?

Comment: Why do you care about the order in which the tests are executed? It's generally a bad idea for tests to depend on each other in any way - they should be independent of each other.

Comment: While that is indeed true for unit tests that isn't the case for integration tests.

Comment: In case someone is wondering how to do this as of 2020: you can use https://github.com/asherber/Xunit.Priority (available on NuGet).

Comment: @Cesar - Thanks for the hint, I'll try it. On NUGET I found also `Xunit.Extensions.Ordering`, but I haven't tried that out (yet) - I think that it orders everything alphabetically.

Comment: Note that with XUnit.Priority you can define a [DefaultPriority(x)] on class level and a [Priority(y)] on method (Fact) level. And tests with the same priority run in alphabetical order - so it might be sufficient to set a default priority on class level and name the tests alphabetically.

Answer (score 56):

In xUnit 2.* this can be achieved using the `TestCaseOrderer` attribute to designate an ordering strategy, which can be used to reference an attribute that is annotated on each test to denote an order.

For example:

**Ordering Strategy**

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)] 

public class PriorityOrderer : ITestCaseOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<TTestCase> OrderTestCases<TTestCase>(IEnumerable<TTestCase> testCases) where TTestCase : ITestCase
    {
        var sortedMethods = new SortedDictionary<int, List<TTestCase>>();

        foreach (TTestCase testCase in testCases)
        {
            int priority = 0;

            foreach (IAttributeInfo attr in testCase.TestMethod.Method.GetCustomAttributes((typeof(TestPriorityAttribute).AssemblyQualifiedName)))
                priority = attr.GetNamedArgument<int>("Priority");

            GetOrCreate(sortedMethods, priority).Add(testCase);
        }

        foreach (var list in sortedMethods.Keys.Select(priority => sortedMethods[priority]))
        {
            list.Sort((x, y) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x.TestMethod.Method.Name, y.TestMethod.Method.Name));
            foreach (TTestCase testCase in list)
                yield return testCase;
        }
    }

    static TValue GetOrCreate<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key) where TValue : new()
    {
        TValue result;

        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result)) return result;

        result = new TValue();
        dictionary[key] = result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Attribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TestPriorityAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestPriorityAttribute(int priority)
    {
        Priority = priority;
    }

    public int Priority { get; private set; }
}
```

**Test Cases**

```
[TestCaseOrderer("FullNameOfOrderStrategyHere", "OrderStrategyAssemblyName")]
public class PriorityOrderExamples
{
    [Fact, TestPriority(5)]
    public void Test3()
    {
        // called third
    }

    [Fact, TestPriority(0)]
    public void Test2()
    {
      // called second
    }

    [Fact, TestPriority(-5)]
    public void Test1()
    {
       // called first
    }

}
```

xUnit 2.* ordering samples [here](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/TestOrderExamples/TestCaseOrdering)

Comment: This worked great only after I added an assembly attribute... [assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]

Comment: Thanks! This may be required since I wrote that answer.

Comment: An "official" example of this can be found [here](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/TestOrderExamples/TestCaseOrdering).
And it's not necessary to use attributes to accomplish this, conventions like alphabetical ordering by method names etc might be used as well.

Comment: Strange, but none of that worked for me. I created 4 EF integration tests, and despite alphabetical ordering and applying Priority it didn't regard the right order. It was always running them in order 4-1-2-3 and I named them Test_01, Test_02, Test_03 and Test_04. The order is important because I used it for CRUD-Testing (create, read, update, delete).

Comment: Note this only works for tests in the same *class* (not collection unfortunately). See https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2217 for a write up.

Answer (score 25):

Testpriority: at the bottom of [this](http://www.bricelam.net/2012/04/xunitnet-extensibility.html) page.

```
[PrioritizedFixture]
public class MyTests
{
    [Fact, TestPriority(1)]
    public void FirstTest()
    {
        // Test code here is always run first
    }
    [Fact, TestPriority(2)]
    public void SeccondTest()
    {
        // Test code here is run second
    }
}
```

BTW, I have the same problem right now. And yes, it is not the clean art.. but QA wanted a manual test.. so an automated test with a specific order already is a big leap for them.. (cough) and yes, it is not really unit testing..

Comment: TestPriority only works on a per-module/class basis. So different classes are still executed in random order. (C# compiler embeds classes in a non predicable order into assembly.) In order to make the testing sequence (testers have a test protocol) easier and repeatable, I added alphabetical sorting. So I created a modified version of xunit 1.9 that executes test classes in alphabetical order. Have a look at http://www.andreas-reiff.de/2012/06/xunit-with-alphabetically-sorted-classes-and-proper-display-list-matching-execution-order/ .

Comment: @bricelam, that link seems broken, it goes into some redirect loop.

Answer (score 18):

If you really have the need to prioritize your tests (probably not your unit tests) you can use [Xunit.Priority](https://github.com/asherber/Xunit.Priority).
I have used it for some integration testing and works really well and simple without the overhead of having to write your prioritization classes, for simple case scenarios

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `XUnit.Priority` didn't work for me. In my test cases, it wasn't running the tests in the priority order specified.

So I tried `XUnitPriorityOrderer`, which is similar to use but was working (To quickly test it, save the following code in a text editor as OrderedXUnitTests.linq, then open it with [LinqPad 6](https://www.linqpad.net/) and execute it. Alternatively, you can also copy the TestClass to Visual Studio and add XUnit, XUnit.Runner.VisualStudio and XUnitPriorityOrderer):

```
<Query Kind="Program">
  <NuGetReference>XUnitPriorityOrderer</NuGetReference>
  <Namespace>Xunit</Namespace>
  <Namespace>XUnitPriorityOrderer</Namespace>
</Query>


#load "xunit"

// using XUnitPriorityOrderer
// see: https://github.com/frederic-prusse/XUnitPriorityOrderer
void Main()
{
    RunTests();  // Call RunTests() or press Alt+Shift+T to initiate testing.
}


#region private::Tests

[TestCaseOrderer(CasePriorityOrderer.TypeName, CasePriorityOrderer.AssembyName)]
public class TestClass
{
    static List<string> Order { get; set; }
    
    public TestClass()
    {
        Order = Order ?? new List<string>();
    }

    [Fact, Order(2)]
    void Test_Xunit_AnotherTest()
    {
        Order.Add("Test_Xunit_AnotherTest");
        Assert.True(3 + 1 == 4);
    }

    [Fact, Order(1)]
    void Test_Xunit()
    {
        Order.Add("Test_XUnit");
        Assert.True(1 + 1 == 2);
    }

    [Fact, Order(99)]
    void Print_Order()
    {
        Order.Add("Print_Order");
        var strOrder = string.Join(", ", Order.ToArray());
        strOrder.Dump("Execution Order");
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}
#endregion
```

This will run the tests in given order (Order(1), Order(2) and then Order(99)) and will dump the executed tests finally (test method Print_Order()).

Answer (score -5):

You can't, by design. It's deliberately random in order to prevent anyone getting one of those either by desire or by accident.

The randomness is only for a given Test class, so you may be able to achieve your goals by wrapping items you want to control the order of inside a nested class - but in that case, you'll still end up with random order whenever you have more than two Test Methods in a class.

If you're trying to manage the building up of fixtures or context, the built-in `IUseFixture<T>` mechanism may be appropriate. See the [xUnit Cheat Sheet](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/04/xunit-cheat-sheet/) for examples.

But you really need to tell us more about what you're trying to do or we'll just have to get speculative.