# How to set Test Priority in xUnit and also to run selective test based on Priority

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I have 2 questions here:

1. How to set Priority of Tests in xUnit
2. How to run selective tests based on Priority

E.g i have 5 tests : T1,T2,T3,T4,T5 having Priorities P1,P2,P1,P2,P3

So I need to run only P1 cases i.e T1,T3 how to do that ?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210281/how-to-set-the-test-case-sequence-in-xunit/40369983#40369983

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that by adding Trait attributes to your test.

More info is outlined here:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/part-2using-traits-with-different-test-frameworks-in-the-unit-test-explorer/
- http://mariangemarcano.blogspot.dk/2010/12/xunitnet-running-tests-testcategory.html?m=1)

Comment: First link is broken