# How to order test cases in xUnit

Tags: xunit

I have the exact case as in this post:
[How to set the test case sequence in XUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210281/how-to-set-the-test-case-sequence-in-xunit)

Which points me to this link:
http://www.bricelam.net/2012/04/xunitnet-extensibility.html

Followed the snippet of code in the post, the one using `RunWithAttribute`.

But as one of the comments in the post pointed out,
once I annotate my test class with  `[PrioritizedFixture]` all of my test classes are no longer recognized by the xUnit Runner in Visual Studio.

Is there anyway to make this work?

*Using VS2013 and xUnit 1.9.2

Comment: I would caution against having a required order. Maybe this is a good time to use setUp() or setUpClass()?

Comment: I believe I am having the same issue: once I annotate my test class with `[PrioritizedFixture]`, the individual test methods do not appear to be recognized as tests.  The session runner usually picks up the tests dynamically when I run the whole test class... however it doesn't always find all the tests, which is very frustrating... There doesn't appear to be any way to run single tests when using `[PrioritizedFixture]`.